# Angular 5 routerLink

Tags: angular, angular5

I have added the routerLink in the button under product.component.html which will redirect to /update-product. Below is the code:

```
<button  routerLink="./update-product" routerLinkActive="active">Edit</button>
```

**When I submit the button, its not redirecting however, no error in the console.**

My product.component.ts is as below:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Title} from "@angular/platform-browser";
import { ProductService } from './product.service';
import { Product } from './product';
import { HttpErrorResponse } from '@angular/common/http';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product',
  templateUrl: './product.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product.component.scss'],
  providers: []
})

export class ProductComponent implements OnInit {
  products: Product[] = [];
  dataInvalid = false;
  formErrors = [];
  formSubmitting = false;
  //title = 'Products';
  countries = [];
  states = [];

  constructor(private productService: ProductService, private title: Title) {  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do it in following way.

```
<button routerLink="/update-product" routerLinkActive="active">Edit</button>
```